# PHP: Getting values from array1 with from nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays. **$array2** to check whether **$array1** value exist in `'slug'`.

```
$array1 = [
    0 => "tenants",
    1 => "modules",
];
```

```
$array2 = [
    "child" => [
        "prefix" => "tenants",
        "slug" => "tenants",
        "child" => [
            [
                "prefix" => "modules/{id}",
                "slug" => "modules"
            ],
            [
                "prefix" => "fetch/{id}",
                "slug" => "fetch"
            ],

        ],
    ],
];
```

My Code:

```
foreach ($array1 as $value) {
    array_walk_recursive($array2['child'],
        function ($item, $key) use (&$result, &$res, &$value) {

            if ($key == "slug") {
                if ($item == $value) {
                    $res[] = $item;
                }

            }
            if ($key == 'prefix') {
                $result[] = $item;
            }

       });
}
```

Here I used array_walk_recursive to check every if array1 is exist in slug. But i want to get also it's prefix.

In my code above It will not get the `modules/{id}` since it's not equal to slug.

**Example**:

```
$array1 = [
    0 => "tenants",
    1 => "modules",
];
```

**Result**:

```
array:3 [▼
  1 => "tenants"
  2 => "modules/{id}"
]
```

Code: https://3v4l.org/E18Uq
Happy coding.

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: Expected Output is in **Result**

Comment: Notice that once `$child` is an element and once is array of childs - this inconsistency is wrong

Comment: @dWinder remove the first 'child' and udpate ```$array2['child']``` to ```$array2```. Updated https://3v4l.org/tGd0b

Comment: Did my answer helped you? @BenchBoy

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `array_walk_recursive` just use custom function as:

```
function getFromChild($item, $asd) {
    if (!is_array($item)) return [];
    $res = [];
    if ($item["slug"] == $asd) // if have slug check and add if needed
        $res[] = $item['prefix'];
    if (isset($item['child']))
        foreach($item['child'] as $child) // for all child loop and add
            $res = array_merge($res, getFromChild($child, $asd));
    return $res;
}
```

Now you can call it with:

```
$res = [];
foreach ($array1 as $asd) {
    $res = array_merge($res, getFromChild($array2, $asd));
}
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/tuODQ)